# In play-json how to get message through MessagesApi in json writes

Tags: json, scala, playframework

There is a class

```
    case class Location(id: Long, label: String, city: String)
```

The city field is the city code, the label of city can be found in message files based on city code, this location is expected to be output as

```
    {id:"", label: "", city:{code:"",label:""}}
```

for example:

```
    Location(1, "location1", "HK")
```

should be output as

```
    {
      id: 1, 
      label: "location1", 
      city: { 
               code: "HK", 
               label: "Hong Kong" 
            }
     }
```

I think, a Json write for city looks like:

```
    val cityWrites: Writes[String] = (
        (JsPath \ "code").write[String] and
        (JsPath \ "label").write[String])( 
            (code: String) => (code-> messagesApi.get(code))
```

Then problem is where I can get a messagesApi, BTW, I put all the writes/reads/formats in a package object,

Comment: It must be resolved using DI: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaI18N